# fineuploader - Invalid policy document or request headers error

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm trying to setup Fine-uploader s3 with cross domain signing. I've been struggling with it for two weeks now, going through every article on the internet and still can't get this to work. I'm, with exaggerating, very frustrated. I've started questioning every line of code and I get nowhere..

I keep receiving the following errors in the browser console:

```
XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://myserver.com/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?v4=true".
util.js:241 [Fine Uploader 5.15.6] Invalid policy document or request headers!
XHR finished loading: POST "https://myserver.com/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?v4=true".
util.js:241 [Fine Uploader 5.15.6] Policy signing failed.  Invalid policy document or request headers!
```

I'm using the php server provided by fineuploader on github to sign documents. Here I've set my constants and modified

```
'access-control-allow-origin: https://myserver.com' and 'access-control-allow-credentials: true'.
```

My javascript uploader script client-side looks like this.

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
  element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
  debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: 'BUCKET_NAME.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com',
        accessKey: 'ACCESS_KEY'
    },
    cors: {
        //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
        expected: true,
      //if you want cookies to be sent along with the request
        sendCredentials: true
    },
    objectProperties: {
        bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
        host: 's3-accelerate.amazonaws.com' // only needed for version 4 signatures
    },
    signature: {
      endpoint: 'https://myserver.com/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php',
      version: 4
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: 'https://myserver.com/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?success'
    },
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ["jpeg", "jpg", "png"],
        acceptFiles: "image/jpeg, image/png",
        sizeLimit: 10000000,
        itemLimit: 1
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true // defaults to false
    },
    paste: {
        targetElement: document,
        promptForName: true
    }
});
```

This is my header information

```
Request URL:https://MYSERVER.com/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?v4=true
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:MY_IP
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://MY_WEBSITE.com
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 31 Jan 2018 17:45:06 GMT
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Server:nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:da-DK,da;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:aeoeaa.club
Origin:https://MY_WEBSITE.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
v4:true
```

And

```
Request URL:https://MYSERVER/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?v4=true
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:MY_IP
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://MYWEBSITE.com
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 31 Jan 2018 17:45:07 GMT
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Server:nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:da-DK,da;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:461
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host:MYSERVER.com
Origin:https://MYWEBSITE.com
Referer:https://MYWEBSITE.com/pages/testpage
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
v4:true
Request Payload
view source
{expiration: "2018-01-31T17:50:06.323Z",…}
conditions
:
[{acl: "private"}, {bucket: "MY_BUCKET_NAME"}, {Content-Type: "image/jpeg"},…]
expiration
:
"2018-01-31T17:50:06.323Z"
```

Everything should be working but I still get the same error. I don't want any of the complicating features. I just want a simple upload to s3. But this seems impossible. I'll gladly supply more info. Anything to get this done. I'll even send a bottle of wine to the one solving it. Nothing I do helps..

Comment: you've left out a very important piece of information, perhaps _the_ most important info: the response from your signature server

Comment: Thanks for always helping Ray. Isn't that what have supplied from the browser console?

I have figured out the problem, by removing one feature at the time in my client side javascript.
It turns out the problem was coursed by setting a size limit. When I removed that. I no longer receive errors and it uploaded successfully for the first time!!!! :)

Comment: Now I'm wondering why it does a OPTIONS and a POST request. The OPTIONS one work and the file is getting uploaded. The POST request gives me a preflight error from AWS.

It seems unnecessary to send both? Can I remove the POST one?
Also how to I restrict file size now?

Comment: Feel a bit dumb now. Figured how to set limit size. Both client side and expected on server side has to be the same, of course.

Thank you, Ray, for providing this tool as open source!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. The browser console does not provide the server response, so in the future you'll want to include that.